# Git push, status issue

Tags: git, push, synchronization, status

I have got a strange error occurring on my git project.

```
liam@development ~/android/system/system/core $ git push git@development:android.git/platform/system/core.git gingerbread-release-om
Everything up-to-date
liam@development ~/android/system/system/core $ git status
# On branch gingerbread-release-om
# Your branch is ahead of 'development/gingerbread-release-om' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
liam@development ~/android/system/system/core $
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Edit:

```
liam@development ~/android/system/system/core $ git remote -v
development     git@development:android/platform/system/core (fetch)
development     git@development:android/platform/system/core (push)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit 2: (I can't answer my own question yet)

Ok, i now know the issue. My network administrator had "Fixed" a bug in the git web by adding .git to root of the android repo. This was done after I had sync'd my local source tree. The remote should now read

```
git@development:android.git/platform/system/core
```

To fix this i needed to run

```
git remote set-url development git@development:android.git/platform/system/core git@development:android/platform/system/core
```

To fix my entire android source tree a ran

```
repo forall -c 'pwd; git remote -v; git remote set-url development git@development:android.git/platform/$REPO_PATH git@development:android/platform/$REPO_PATH; git remote -v'
```

from the root of source tree. Got a little bit extra in there for clarity of the change.

Once fixed I ran:

```
liam@development ~/android/system/system/core $ git status
# On branch gingerbread-release-om
# Your branch is ahead of 'development/gingerbread-release-om' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
liam@development ~/android/system/system/core $ git push
Everything up-to-date
liam@development ~/android/system/system/core $ git status
# On branch gingerbread-release-om
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
liam@development ~/android/system/system/core $
```

Sorted!

Answer (score 1):

Because when you are pushing to a url, git doesn't update any remote branches.

You should push to `development gingerbread-release-om` for that message to disappear.

Comment: When i do that, git doesn't know where to find the repo, i get `ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Repository read access denied
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`. If i clone the repo, its is correct, displays the local and remote branch in the correct place (using gitg for graphical representation), but if i do it on my problem repo it, thinks the remote branch's head i way back.

Comment: What does git remote show development show (please edit your question)?